# Option or setting to open non SO links in mobile browser

Tags: feature-request, bug, android-app

Non SO links currently are opened in SO Android app's internal browser window. Need an option or a setting to have the links open in mobile's default browser.

Why?

1. I prefer the default browser because the link gets added to my browsing history. Also, default browser does better rendering & handling of stuff like session.
2. I can switch between SO app and browser window.